# How do I use a confirmation model before proceeding to a dynamically created link in a Jinja2 template?

Tags: html, jinja2, crud, bootstrap-5

I am trying to delete a record that was inserted into an HTML table created inside of a Jinja2 template.  I would like to confirm before deleting. I am using Bootstrap5 if that matters.

This works but without the confirmation model.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>      
      <tr>        
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for u in users %}
        {% set uid = u[0] %}
        {% set first = u[2] %}
        {% set last = u[3] %}
        {% set email = u[4] %}
        {% set password = u[5] %}
        <tr>
          
          <td>{{last}}, {{first}}</td>
          <td>{{email}}</td>
          <td>{{password}}</td>   
          <td>
            <a href="/processDeleteUser/{{uid}}" class="btn btn-light" role="button"><i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i></a>

          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}      
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

However, when I try to delete with the confirmation model the UID (record id) in the URL gets changed to the first record in the table. This, of course, causes the wrong record to be deleted. The following is the code with the confirmation model:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>      
      <tr>        
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for u in users %}
        {% set uid = u[0] %}
        {% set first = u[2] %}
        {% set last = u[3] %}
        {% set email = u[4] %}
        {% set password = u[5] %}
        <tr>
          
          <td>{{last}}, {{first}}</td>
          <td>{{email}}</td>
          <td>{{password}}</td>          
          <td>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#confirmModal">
              <i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i>
            </button>
            
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="confirmModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this user?
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a href="/processDeleteUser/{{uid}}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>                     
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}      
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

What can I do to keep the UID from changing when using the model?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems that I can see from your code.

1. You are trying to use anchor tag to remove something, which is not appropriate by HTTP standard, because it is doing a `GET` request. You should use `DELETE` request instead.
2. You are creating a modal for each of your row record. This is fine, but they are all using the same id, which will render warnings if you open your console in your browser. When you attempt to call your modal by id (action from your button), the calling will be an unpredictable action.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>      
      <tr>        
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for u in users %}
        {% set uid = u[0] %}
        {% set first = u[2] %}
        {% set last = u[3] %}
        {% set email = u[4] %}
        {% set password = u[5] %}
        <tr>
          
          <td>{{last}}, {{first}}</td>
          <td>{{email}}</td>
          <td>{{password}}</td>          
          <td>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#confirmModal-{{uid}}">
              <i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i>
            </button>
            
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal-{{uid}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="confirmModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmModalLabel-{{uid}}">Confirm Delete</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this user?
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button onclick="deleteUser({{uid}})" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>                     
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
  function deleteUser(uid) {
    fetch('/processDeleteUser/' + uid, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
  </script>
```

I have changed the id for the modals, which is suffixed by the uid to make them unique. This is just for the template, from the `processDeleteUser` endpoint in flask, you will need to change the accepted method to `DELETE` to make this work. You may also want to change the console log to handle the response of delete in a more custom way.

Another item worth noting is that you using list for your users object, it will work but it is recommended to use `User` class instead.